# How to retry N jobs using Sidekiq::RetrySet?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I used

```
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.retry_all
```

this retry all my failed jobs. 
I have 10 000 failed jobs and wanted retry only first 20 or 30

```
   @query = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new
    @test = @query.select[1..20] do |job|
     job.retry
    end
```

what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example won't work, but `Sidekiq::RetrySet` does include `Enumerable` so you can do something like:

```
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.first(20).each { |job| job.retry }
```

Comment: bschaeffer 
you really helped me, thanks - this work ^^).